# How can I connect my Ionic app running in my android device to my node server in my pc (localhost)?

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework, server

I am using Ionic to build an android app and a node server to connect to postgres database. I can connect to my node server using ionic serve in the web browser of my computer.
Now when I build the app for android and use it in the device, it cannot connect to node server.

I have access to the localhost in my device (verified using the android device browser) but the ionic app does not connect.
This is what I tried so far:

- Allow access in the apache server to the folder where the node server is running
- Fix CORS resource sharing in node server.
- Add whitelist cordova plugin in the ionic app.
- Change localhost to 102.133.44.2 (ip of my pc) in http querys located in http provider in ionic app.

Any idea would be helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Same Wifi Network you can connect your local nodeJS Server to your Mobile.

Open CMD & Run Command:

`ipconfig`

It will show you your Local IP address. Copy that `IPv4` address `Example: 192.168.100.69`

Replace it with your localhost address `http://localhost:3100/login` to `http://192.168.100.69:3100/login` inside your mobile application and you can use it in your mobile.

Use Chrome Debug tool to Check debug your app:
To use Chrome Debug type `chrome://inspect/#devices` in your chrome Search bar.

Connect your Mobile(enable Developer option & USB debugging from settings) via Cable you will see your device slick on it a New debugger window will open. check console for errors / warnings.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it is not possible yet to connect my ionic app to my computer.

Comment: Are you connect to same WiFi in Both devices??

Comment: yes, i am, as i said above i can access my pc from my mobile using the android web browser, but i cannot connect to the node server from the ionic app

Comment: Are you getting any error? Have you tried to debug your application via chrome debug tool!! Also share your HTTP API code.

Comment: No there is no error, just the app doesnt connect. I do not know how could I use chrome debug tool. My code can be seen in this repository https://github.com/henryf3/IonicBackup

Comment: The HTTP api code is located in IonicBackup/src/providers/rest/rest.ts

Comment: Check Answer again i update it how to use chrome debugger.

Comment: Thanks I will try :)